# What could be causing 'Py4JError' when calling 'spark.createDataFrame' on PySpark SQL Session?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, py4j

I have installed Apache Spark, Java and Python. I am using a Jupyter notebook. I have an error when creating a dataframe.

I write:

```py
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
spark = (SparkSession
        .builder
        .appName("AuthorsAges")
        .getOrCreate())
```

And it runs without any errors. But now, I write:

```
data_df = spark.createDataFrame([("Brooke", 20), ("Denny", 31), ("Jules", 30), ("TD", 35), ("Brooke", 25)], ["name", "age"])
```

And the error is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 2
      1 #Create a DataFrame
----> 2 data_df = spark.createDataFrame([("Brooke", 20), ("Denny", 31), ("Jules", 30), ("TD", 35),      ("Brooke", 25)], ["name", "age"])

File C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py:1276, in SparkSession.createDataFrame(self,   data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
   1271 if has_pandas and isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
   1272     # Create a DataFrame from pandas DataFrame.
   1273     return super(SparkSession, self).createDataFrame(  # type: ignore[call-overload]
   1274         data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema
   1275     )
-> 1276 return self._create_dataframe(
   1277     data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema  # type: ignore[arg-type]
   1278 )

    File C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py:1318, in SparkSession._create_dataframe(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
   1316     rdd, struct = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
   1317 else:
-> 1318     rdd, struct = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
   1319 assert self._jvm is not None
   1320 jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())

File C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py:962, in SparkSession._createFromLocal(self, data, schema)
    959     data = list(data)
    961 if schema is None or isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
--> 962     struct = self._inferSchemaFromList(data, names=schema)
    963     converter = _create_converter(struct)
    964     tupled_data: Iterable[Tuple] = map(converter, data)

File C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py:834, in SparkSession._inferSchemaFromList(self, data, names)
    832     raise ValueError("can not infer schema from empty dataset")
    833 infer_dict_as_struct = self._jconf.inferDictAsStruct()
--> 834 infer_array_from_first_element = self._jconf.legacyInferArrayTypeFromFirstElement()
    835 prefer_timestamp_ntz = is_timestamp_ntz_preferred()
    836 schema = reduce(
    837     _merge_type,
    838     (
   (...)
    847     ),
    848 )

File C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:169, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    167 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    168     try:
--> 169         return f(*a, **kw)
    170     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    171         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:330, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client,   target_id, name)
    326         raise Py4JJavaError(
    327             "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328             format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329     else:
--> 330         raise Py4JError(
    331             "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332             format(target_id, ".", name, value))
    333 else:
    334     raise Py4JError(
    335         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}".
    336         format(target_id, ".", name))

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o28.legacyInferArrayTypeFromFirstElement. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method legacyInferArrayTypeFromFirstElement([]) does not exist
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

How do I solve: Py4JError when using spark.createDataFrame?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the installed Java was lower than required for version `>=3.4.0`. [As stated in the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/#downloading):

> Spark runs on Java 8/11/17, Scala 2.12/2.13, Python 3.7+, and R 3.5+. Python 3.7 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.4.0. **Java 8 prior to version 8u362 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.4.0.** [...]

After updating Java to 11, the error was gone with both pyspark `3.4.1` and `3.5.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have inconsistencies with your Spark versions installed.

You have your Pyspark code that tries to call the [`legacyInferArrayTypeFromFirstElement`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/87a5442f7ed96b11051d8a9333476d080054e5a0/python/pyspark/sql/session.py#L834) method of the underlying [`SQLConf`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/87a5442f7ed96b11051d8a9333476d080054e5a0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L4971-L4972) object, which has only been introduced since since [v3.4.0](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/87a5442f7ed96b11051d8a9333476d080054e5a0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L4077-L4084).

But since your error is

> py4j.Py4JException: Method legacyInferArrayTypeFromFirstElement([]) does not exist

I would think that your underlying Spark installation is not on version 3.4.0. This is of course dependent on how you have Spark installed so it's hard to say exactly. Try to verify which version your Pyspark is using (should be 3.4.0) and which version of Spark the executors start up with.